# fsocketopen() Not connecting to server?

Tags: php, curl, irc

I've been trying to connect to a Twitch chat via IRC. I've added an echo function to test where I had connected or not as that page was blank and an account didn't join the IRC.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

$datatwitch= array(
        'server' => 'irc.twitch.tv',
        'port' => 6667,
        'nick' => 'greatbritishbgbot',
        'name' => 'greatbritishbgbot',
        'pass' => 'oauth:HERE',
    );
    ?>
<?php 
//The server host is the IP or DNS of the IRC server. 
$server_host = $datatwitch['server'];  
//Server Port, this is the port that the irc server is running on. Deafult: 6667 
$server_port = $datatwitch['port'];  
//Server Chanel, After connecting to the IRC server this is the channel it will join. 
$server_chan = "#greatbritishbg"; 

//login password 
$nickname = $datatwitch['name']; 
$nickname_pass = $datatwitch['pass']; 

    //Ok, We have a nickname, now lets connect. 
    $server = array(); //we will use an array to store all the server data. 
    //Open the socket connection to the IRC server 
    $server['SOCKET'] = @fsockopen($server_host, $server_port, $errno, $errstr, 2); 
    if($server['SOCKET']) 
    { 
        //Ok, we have connected to the server, now we have to send the login commands. 
        echo "connected";
          SendCommand("PASS $nickname_pass \n\r"); //Sends the password not needed for most servers 
          SendCommand("NICK $nickname\n\r"); //sends the nickname 
          SendCommand("USER $nickname USING PHP IRC\n\r"); //sends the user must have 4 paramters 
        while(!feof($server['SOCKET'])) //while we are connected to the server 
        { 
            $server['READ_BUFFER'] = fgets($server['SOCKET'], 1024); //get a line of data from the server 
            echo "[RECIVE] ".$server['READ_BUFFER']."<br>\n\r"; //display the recived data from the server 

            /* 
            IRC Sends a "PING" command to the client which must be anwsered with a "PONG" 
            Or the client gets Disconnected 
            */ 
            //Now lets check to see if we have joined the server 
            if(strpos($server['READ_BUFFER'], "422")) //422 is the message number of the MOTD for the server (The last thing displayed after a successful connection) 
            { 
                //If we have joined the server 

                SendCommand("JOIN $server_chan\n\r"); //Join the chanel 
            } 
            if(substr($server['READ_BUFFER'], 0, 6) == "PING :") //If the server has sent the ping command 
            { 
                SendCommand("PONG :".substr($server['READ_BUFFER'], 6)."\n\r"); //Reply with pong 
                //As you can see i dont have it reply with just "PONG" 
                //It sends PONG and the data recived after the "PING" text on that recived line 
                //Reason being is some irc servers have a "No Spoof" feature that sends a key after the PING 
                //Command that must be replied with PONG and the same key sent. 
            } 
            flush(); //This flushes the output buffer forcing the text in the while loop to be displayed "On demand" 
        } 
    } else {
        echo "connection failed";
    }
function SendCommand ($cmd) 
{ 
    global $server; //Extends our $server array to this function 
    @fwrite($server['SOCKET'], $cmd, strlen($cmd)); //sends the command to the server 
    echo "[SEND] $cmd <br>"; //displays it on the screen 
} 
?>
```

It appears I can't Get passed `if($server['SOCKET'])`. Is there anyway I can diagnose this? As I have directly connect with the details in hexChat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server had actually been preventing me to use fsocket. After contacting my host and moving away from a shared host it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24835967/1163786

Especially:

```
$socket = fsockopen($bot["Host"], $bot["Port"], $error1, $error2);
if(!$socket) {
    echo 'Crap! fsockopen failed. Details: ' . $error1 . ': ' . $error2;
}
```

To get the details about the socket error = reason for socket not connecting.

Currently, you have `$errno, $errstr` on `fsockopen`, but echo only "connection failed".

Comment: Hey Jens, I've been reading the thread. It kinda needs to be done via PHP. (Unless there's an easier way to incorporate a script I've written in PHP with it).